# Ruby on Rails posting nested a nested hash to strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm posting a hash from my ruby app, to an api built in ruby using strong params.

My post looks like this:

```
resp = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, 'order' => @order.to_json, 'max' => '50')
```

The issue is, that this doesn't work with strong params

```
[3] pry(#<Api::V1::OrdersController>)> order_params
NoMethodError: undefined method `permit' for #<String:0x007feb6890acf8>
```

How do I post this correctly?  Also, I'd like to post a nested has under order as well.

```
params[:order][:pickup_attribute]
```

How can I also send that through?

Answer (score 0):

You are posting `order` as a String. Try this:

```
resp = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, 'order' => @order.as_json, 'max' => '50')
```

Notice the `as_json` (returns a Hash) instead of `to_json` (which returns a String). If it does not work, I would like to see your controller's implementation.